# Can anyone explain this sed command to me?

Tags: bash, shell, sed, command-line

I have just taken over someone's code while they are away, most of it is coherent but I came across thsi command and I can't quite work out what it's doing:

```
sed 's@.*@@' filename.txt > filename2.txt
```

I've tested it and it seems to be a convoluted way of copying a file, unfortunately I don't hve access to his original file to run it on that. Can anyone help?

Comment: `@` is just a delimiter, usually `/` is used, but you can substitute any other char as well.  Here it deletes all the lines and creates an empty output file with the same length with the input file.

Comment: The 'same length' @karafka refers to is 'the same number of lines' but each line consists of just a newline (an empty line).

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know @ could be used as a delimiter, it really threw me off.

Comment: Some other character is most commonly used when `/` is part of the pattern, for example parsing filename paths.  Most confusing character I have seen used is a comma, e.g. `s,.*,,`.

Answer (score -2):

I found few references which might help you.

1. `sed 's@/usr/local@@'` is use to delete `/usr/local` from input text.  http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html
2. `.*` matches all the characters in a string (including the empty string).

https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html

I your case `sed 's@.*@@' filename.txt > filename2.txt` will read filename.txt file every character and make copy.

Comment: not quite -- this will read every character (except newlines) in filename.txt, and replace it with nothing in filename2.txt.   I'm guessing the intention had to do with counting the number of lines in the file, in which case, you may want to lookup `wc -l`, which would be more efficient...